# Why does compiling Spark application from within sbt session fail with "object apache is not a member of package org"?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I've created a simple file `hello.scala` containing the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object HelloSbt extends App {
  println("Welcome to this thing!")
}
```

Please note that I'm not using an IDE.

When I run the command `compile` I get this error:

> object apache is not a member of package org

The code without the import line works fine.

I looked online and they say I should modify `build.sbt` and add some lines to it. `build.sbt` looks as follows:

```
name := "tasky"
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.9.0-incubating",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "0.9.0-incubating",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "0.9.0-incubating")
```

`compile` keeps failing with the error though. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've started sbt and are in sbt shell, any changes to `build.sbt` are **not** picked up by the shell until you do `reload` (that will reload any changes made since the session was started).

```
sbt:so> help reload
reload

    (Re)loads the project in the current directory.

reload plugins

    (Re)loads the plugins project (under project directory).

reload return

    (Re)loads the root project (and leaves the plugins project).
```

---

There are two issues with your `build.sbt`.

1. You should use the latest and greatest `2.2.0` as the version of the Spark dependencies.
2. Spark supports Scala 2.11 and so `scalaVersion` should be `2.11.8` (up to `2.11.11`).